# Python cannot seem to find libraries - conflict between user and system python versions

Tags: python

So lets start from the very very top.

This is the problem I am currently having:

```
bob@me:~/cloud/simtk/opensim_core_install/lib/python2.7/site-packages$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import opensim
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "opensim/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from common import *
  File "opensim/common.py", line 21, in <module>
    _common = swig_import_helper()
  File "opensim/common.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_common')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named _common
```

For those interested in the specifics, I am trying to use this [package](https://github.com/opensim-org/opensim-core), and specifically the bleeding edge version.

From what I can deign from the world wide web and other sources, I have two versions of python installed on my machine

```
bob@me:/usr$ which python && python --version
/usr/bin/python
Python 2.7.6
```

and

```
bob@me:/usr/local$ /usr/local/bin/python2.7 --version
Python 2.7.9
```

Now, when building the above package one has to make reference to the `libpython2.7.so` files of which I have two (and they are both system, which is to say that none are located in `/usr/local/`:

```
bob@me:/usr$ find . -name 'libpython2.7.so'
./lib/python2.7/config-x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so
./lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so
```

and I built the wrappings by running

```
python setup.py install
```

inside

```
~/cloud/simtk/opensim_core_install/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

which is where it resides. Now when it runs it puts it all in the `/usr/local/` dir rather than the system wide one, and this is where I think problems appear.

```
bob@me:~/cloud/simtk/opensim_core_install/lib/python2.7/site-packages$ sudo python setup.py install
[sudo] password for bob: 
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing opensim.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to opensim.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to opensim.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
reading manifest file 'opensim.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'opensim.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg
running install_lib
running build_py
creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg
creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/opensim
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/opensim/_analyses.so -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/opensim
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/opensim/tools.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/opensim
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/opensim/simbody.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/opensim
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/opensim/actuators.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/opensim
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/opensim/_simbody.so -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/opensim
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/opensim/__init__.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/opensim
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/opensim/analyses.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/opensim
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/opensim/_simulation.so -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/opensim
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/opensim/version.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/opensim
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/opensim/_tools.so -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/opensim
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/opensim/_actuators.so -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/opensim
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/opensim/common.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/opensim
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/opensim/simulation.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/opensim
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/opensim/_common.so -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/opensim
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/opensim/__init__.pyc -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/opensim
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/opensim/tools.py to tools.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/opensim/simbody.py to simbody.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/opensim/actuators.py to actuators.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/opensim/analyses.py to analyses.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/opensim/version.py to version.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/opensim/common.py to common.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/opensim/simulation.py to simulation.pyc
creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying opensim.egg-info/PKG-INFO -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying opensim.egg-info/SOURCES.txt -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying opensim.egg-info/dependency_links.txt -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying opensim.egg-info/top_level.txt -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
writing build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO/native_libs.txt
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
opensim.actuators: module references __file__
opensim.tools: module references __file__
opensim.analyses: module references __file__
opensim.simbody: module references __file__
opensim.common: module references __file__
opensim.simulation: module references __file__
creating 'dist/opensim-4.0-py2.7.egg' and adding 'build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg' to it
removing 'build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg' (and everything under it)
Processing opensim-4.0-py2.7.egg
removing '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/opensim-4.0-py2.7.egg' (and everything under it)
creating /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/opensim-4.0-py2.7.egg
Extracting opensim-4.0-py2.7.egg to /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
opensim 4.0 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Installed /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/opensim-4.0-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for opensim==4.0
Finished processing dependencies for opensim==4.0
```

Now presumably because this is all created in `/usr/local/` that would be why the system version of python cannot find the associated libraries? Problem is that when I try to use `/usr/local/bin/python2.7` it still cannot find the libraries.

Also I should add:

```
bob@me:~/cloud/simtk/opensim_core_install/lib/python2.7/site-packages$ ls *
setup.py

build:
bdist.linux-x86_64  lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

dist:
opensim-4.0-py2.7.egg

opensim:
actuators.py   _analyses.so  _common.so    simbody.py   simulation.py   tools.py
_actuators.so  common.py     __init__.py   simbody.pyc  _simulation.so  _tools.so
analyses.py    common.pyc    __init__.pyc  _simbody.so  tests           version.py

opensim.egg-info:
dependency_links.txt  PKG-INFO  SOURCES.txt  top_level.txt
```

and

```
bob@me:~$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH 
:/local/bob/cloud/simtk/opensim_core_install/lib/python2.7/site-packages/opensim
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I get by your question you tried building by simply running `python setup.py install`.

You have to follow the instructions in the Readme and build with the method corresponding to your operating system instead.

Comment: There is no readme, there is this: https://github.com/simbody/simbody/tree/Simbody-3.5.3#linux-or-mac-using-make and this: https://github.com/opensim-org/opensim-core

Comment: I literally have no idea what you are referring to; the installation directory does not have a readme. Which file browser are you talking about, and which part of the issue above are you trying to address? Because all works, it is the python wrappings that are get messed up.